# Use Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices from Powershell Core?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-core, sqlpackage

I'm trying to use `DacServices` from a Powershell Core script. Unfortunately, it seems DacServices requires `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventDescriptor`, which isn't available in .NET 6. I'm using Powershell Core 7.2.5. Is there a convenient way around this?

I'm loading the types with this code:

```
$sqlServerDacPaths = "${env:ProgramFiles}\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll", "${env:ProgramFiles}\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll"

foreach ($path in $sqlServerDacPaths) {
    if (Test-Path $path) {
        Write-Host "Adding $path"
        Add-Type -Path $path
    }
}

# Instantiate DacServices
$dacServices = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $connectionString
```

The exception I get instantiating `DacServices` is:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices' threw an exception...
> Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventDescriptor' from
> assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0

I've tried both the SQL 15 and 16 versions of `DacServices` without luck.

Comment: Although consuming NuGet packages in PowerShell is a bit of a chore, the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx/) package does have Core support, and you're likely to have more success with those than the stuff that comes with SQL Server itself, since that has largely not transitioned away from Framework yet. For less advanced scenarios invoking [`SqlPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage) directly is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late anwser, you can try running the script in lower version of Powershell, Powershell 5.1 is built on top of the .NET Framework v4.5 which has access to type
System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventDescriptor

It worked in my case:

```
powershell -Version 5.1 pathToYourScript
```